# Add a CSS rule to a div based on select box option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table for a disciplinary action form. there are 5 types of disciplinary action, warnings and severity levels. the top severity level is suspension and it has several extra table fields. these fields are hidden by default via CSS. When someone selects the dropdown option "Suspension" these fields should become visible.

this was my most recent attempt to solve this but it too is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var num = "suspn";
                $("#i_action option").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() === num) { // EDITED THIS LINE
                        sus();
                    }
                    else { // EDITED THIS LINE
                        unsus();
                    }
                });
            });
            function sus() {
                document.getElementById("susp").className += "susp_show";
            }
            function unsus() {
                document.getElementById("susp").className -= "susp_show";
            }
</script>
```

and the html:

```
<select id="i_action" name="i_action">
    <option value="verbl">Verbal Warning</option>
    <option value="1warn">1st Written Warning</option>
    <option value="2warn">2nd Written Warning</option>
    <option value="3warn">3rd Written Warning</option>
    <option value="suspn">Suspension</option>
</select>
<table class="offence" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td>Employee Name:</td> <td><input disabled="true" style="color: #222" type="text" value="<?= $ename00 ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Today's Date:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="<?= $today = date("m/d/y") ?> " /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date of Infraction:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="<?= $today = date("m/d/y") ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr id="susp"><td>Length of suspension:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="" /></td></tr>
    <tr id="susp"><td>Suspension Start Date:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" /></td></tr>
    <tr id="susp"><td>Suspension End Date:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Reason For Action:</td> <td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Employee Comments</td> <td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>
</table>
```

the css:

```
#susp{display: none;}
.susp_show{display: table-row !important;}
```

Comment: I take it that you have added jquery library somewhere, what does the console say ?

Comment: the console is empty and yes JQuery is loaded. have no errors or warning as in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a space to your add and remove className `+= " susp_show"`. it's currently making the class `Someclassnamesusp_show`. ps, ID's should be unique within a document, just noticed you have 3 tr'3 with id susp

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                
                $("#i_action").change(function(){
                 if($(this).val()=="suspn"){ 
                          
                             $('.susp').css('display','block');
                           
                       }else{
                         $('.susp').css('display','none');
                         }
                    
                });
   
            });
```

```css
.susp{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="i_action" name="i_action">
    <option value="verbl">Verbal Warning</option>
    <option value="1warn">1st Written Warning</option>
    <option value="2warn">2nd Written Warning</option>
    <option value="3warn">3rd Written Warning</option>
    <option value="suspn">Suspension</option>
</select>
<table class="offence" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td>Employee Name:</td> <td><input disabled="true" style="color: #222" type="text" value="<?= $ename00 ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Today's Date:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="<?= $today = date("m/d/y") ?> " /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Date of Infraction:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="<?= $today = date("m/d/y") ?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr class="susp"><td>Length of suspension:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="" /></td></tr>
    <tr class="susp"><td>Suspension Start Date:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" /></td></tr>
    <tr class="susp"><td>Suspension End Date:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Reason For Action:</td> <td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Employee Comments</td> <td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you're using jquery already, I would also recommend using jquery's addClass and removeClass methods rather than editing the className.

Comment: Well, I was referring to the OP's use of `className +=`, and in your answer you begin by pointing out that he's missing a space. Instead of just adding a space, he could use `$('#susp').addClass('susp_show')` and removeClass for the other case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.change` on the `<select>` element and use classes (instead of id's) to target elements that need to be shown/hidden.

Example:

```
// inside document.ready
$('#i_action').on('change', function (event) {
    var val = event.target.value; // or $(this).val()
    if (val === "suspn") {
        $('.susp').show();
    } else {
        $('.susp').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 elements with same id which is not allowed in HTML. You can change them to class as a class can be applied to multiple HTML elements.

```
<tr class="susp"><td>Length of suspension:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr class="susp"><td>Suspension Start Date:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" /></td></tr>
<tr class="susp"><td>Suspension End Date:</td> <td> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" /></td></tr>
```

If you are just trying to add/remove class then use the jQuery function for it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#i_action").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "suspn") {
      $(".susp").addClass("susp_show"); //add class
    } else {
      $(".susp").removeClass("susp_show"); //remove class
    }
  });
});
```

Also, `susp_show` class has to have the correct css logic.

```
.susp {
  display: none;
}

.susp_show {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: display:block will not work. it must be display:table-row because these are table rows. if you set to block the columns stack on top of each other

Comment: @JLGriffin I didn't realise that. Updated the code. Also learned something new.